# Can't Read in two strings separated by a space

Tags: c++

I am trying to read in two strings separated by a space.

cin>>a;
cin>>b;

This should technically work. I have also used getline but it doesnt seem to work.
It reads in some of the inputs and gets stuck on others

**Edit:** Added C++ tag, kept C tag since it's part of the original post.

Comment: Indeed, this should work? What's your problem? What's your code? We aren't psychic. (At least not all of us are.)

Comment: This will not work in C because the `cin` and operator `>>` are a part of the C++ language.

Comment: Still shouldn't be in the C area; no C-not-C++ programmer will understand it.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the smallest program that compiles and demonstrates the issue.  Include all errors and warnings from the compiler.  Please state the expected and actual results.  Also, indicate compiler and platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("wrgl zrgl");
    std::string s1, s2;
    iss >> s1 >> s2;
    std::cout << '"' << s1 << "\" \"" << s2 << "\"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

compiles, runs, and prints `"wrgl" "zrgl"` on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

> I have also used getline but it doesnt seem to work. It reads in some of the inputs and gets stuck on others

I am trying to answer this part. Was cin taking enter key for second input?

You may try following way

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    cout << "Enter name1 :";
    string name1;
    getline(std::cin, name1);


    cout << "Enter name2 :";
    string name2;
    getline(std::cin, name2);

    if (name2.empty()) getline(std::cin, name2);

    cout << endl << "Input Name1  :" << name1 << endl << "Input Name2 :" << name2;

     return 0;
}
```

Or you can use ***endl*** to flush the stream

```
void GettingTwoStrings2()
{
    cout << "Enter name1 :" << endl;
    string name1;
    getline(std::cin, name1);


    cout << "Enter name2 :" << endl;
    string name2;
    getline(std::cin, name2);

    cout << endl << "Input Name1  :" << name1 << endl << "Input Name2 :" << name2 << endl;;
}
```